# Linux RPM install package script failure to change ownership of required file

Tags: linux, shell, installation, rpm

Testing usage of RPM install package shell script.

Have included linux commands within the shell script to create a new user and change ownership of /etc/hosts to that user. Shell script content:

```
useradd bob
chown bob /etc/hosts
```

Post RPM install this should result in:

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 bob root 331 Jan  4 11:13 /etc/hosts
```

Instead after RPM install completion it remains:

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 331 Jan  4 11:13 /etc/hosts
```

Comment: What user are you running the script as?

Comment: This is a terrible, terrible idea.

Comment: Appreciated this isnt a fanastic idea but im only experimenting..

Answer (score 0):

`/etc/hosts` is owned by `root` so chances are the script doesn't have privileges to alter that file.

I'm not sure how you are executing the script, however if it's just a standard shell script you could try [`sudo`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo):

```
sudo ./my_script.sh
```

Comment: The RPM installation is carried out using yum as root user.
The script is an internal components of the RPM package and thus is fired during the yum install process.

If i'm following your logic properly are you suggesting that the even with the install process itself being carried out by superuser, the script file within the RPM package itself must also have the correct root proviledges?

Comment: It's one possibility. Another is that the script isn't being run or it's failing. Maybe you could update your question and include all of the relevant source (the script and spec file).

Answer (score 0):

(Caveat: changing ownership of system-level files like this is a security issue and not the smartest idea.)

Are you sure the script is run? You may want to make the first line:

```
useradd bob || /bin/true
```

or just

```
useradd bob || :
```

so that it always returns true. Otherwise `rpm` will abort the script if, for example, the user "bob" already exists.